# Unable to send mail from php script on ubuntu 16

Tags: php, email, ubuntu

I have a php script to send a mail which isn't working on ubuntu server. But after logging in from server if i fire this command

```
echo "body" | mail -s "subject" root
```

then it works properly..im also able to receive email from this command but not using the script from the code

Can anyone tell me what wrong am i doing?

This is my PHP Script to send email :

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Sending HTML email using PHP</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$to = "test@gmail.com";
$subject = "This is subject";

$message = " Testing email service from my website. ";


$header = "From: someone@gmail.com \r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

$retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

if( $retval == true ) {
echo "Message sent successfully ...";
}else {
echo "Message could not be sent...";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: The page says Message sent successfully... but i don't receive the email.

Comment: OK 2 things... Spam folder checked? And error log checked?

Comment: Email doesn't exist in spam folder too but my error log says something like this

/usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
sendmail: Cannot open mail:25

Comment: There you have it. in the php.ini you have to configure how php sends mails. Check it out: https://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm

Comment: I have it configured already. My Php.ini file has this 

SMTP localhost localhost
smtp_port 25 25

Comment: It still tries to use sendmail. check it if sendmail is activated...

Answer (score 0):

In the file php.ini you have to configure how php should send mails. You can use sendmail and configure SMTP there.

Comment: In my php.ini file i have SMTP configuration like this 

SMTP localhost localhost
smtp_port 25 25

Comment: Do you have an SMTP on localhost on port 25?

Comment: Yes that's how it is

Comment: sendmail is deactivated?

Comment: I tried installing sendmail but during installation in between it says creating SSL Certificates for sendmail and then anything doesn't happen

Comment: Can u execute sendmail by commandline?

Comment: No, there is no way to do it

Comment: is it win or unix?

Comment: Ubuntu 16 server

Comment: In unix do: echo "Subject: test" | /usr/lib/sendmail -v replace.me@with.your.mail.address.com